# How do i comment/uncomment with macvim

Tags: vim, macvim

How do you comment and uncomment out a code block with janus macvim

The [janus](https://github.com/carlhuda/janus) documentation for [nerdcommenter](https://github.com/ddollar/nerdcommenter) says that binding is

```
Janus binds command-/ (`<D-/>`) to toggle comments
```

What does that mean in keystrokes...my leader key is the comma

**UPDATE**

After reading the nerdcommenter doc it seems like that might not be what i need to comment...any ideas

Comment: My recommendation. Get rid of janus and install nerdcommenter yourself. So you know how it is set up. (It will be more helpful in the long run if you know how everything is set up in your vim configuration. Debugging will be hard down the road if you continue to use Janus)

Answer (score 5):

It just means pressing keys <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>/</kbd>.

Comment: Is it not fair to assume that a MacVim user is on a Mac?

Comment: @eleom: I tried your key combination on my macbook mountain lion 10.8 macvim and instead of block commenting the selected line I see a forward slash at the bottom. I checked my keyboard shortcuts and don't see any command + forward slash definition. Do you know what might be the problem? I did follow the instruction here to allow macvim to always open up new file as a tab, rather than a new window: http://webexpose.org/2008/10/13/open-macvim-tabs-from-command-line/comment-page-1/#comment-95424

Comment: @eleom: apology for the uninformed question above. I thought block commenting by mouse was natively supported by macvim.

Answer (score 3):

1. The `Cmd` key (or Apple key on old keyboards) is represented in MacVim as `<D>`.
2. That key can only be seen by MacVim in "GUI mode". This means that, like with a lot of crap in Janus and other distributions, you end up learning someone else's crappy non-portable mappings instead of *your* own cross-platform mappings.
3. The `<D-key>` notation means exactly the same thing as the usual `Cmd+key` so `<D-/>` is the same as `Cmd+/`: press the `Cmd` key, press the `/` key and release both at the same time. Like in TextMate.
4. NERDCommenter is a popular commenter plugin. Why the Janus maintainers chose it over other plugins is unknown but it works well.

Comment: Your second point there is interesting, as I am trying to figure out why the Cmd-/ mapping does not work in a terminal session. Are you saying the Cmd button is not seen by terminal applications?

Comment: I see that NERDCommenter hijacks this key combo in MacVim, but it is not mentioned anywhere in the documentation for NERDCommenter. Know why this happens?

Answer (score 1):

Press the Command (⌘) and forward slash (/) keys simultaneously. You can prefix this with a modifier (e.g. number of lines) for more complicated effects.